# Generate tfrecord.py : UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode byte

Tags: python, unicode, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord, labelimg

I converted the xml files I created in the label img file to csv and I want to convert them to a tf record file from there. I tried many ways and looked at many forums and videos, but I still cannot solve the problem. I keep getting the same error. I still cannot solve this problem. Thank you in advance for your help
My Code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict


flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'raccoon':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

I used to run the codes in the tensorflow library as flags v1, I added the unidecode library and even deleted the utf8 encoding and tried it as blank, then I even tried latin-1 and 3 other different codes, I tried the ios library and many more methods, I even tried the colab google, but it still didn't work
My Code Erorr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\custom object\generate_tfrecord.py", line 91, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\custom object\generate_tfrecord.py", line 77, in main
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\tf_record.py", line 294, in __init__
    super(TFRecordWriter, self).__init__(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 48: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The `__future__` imports you have were in the future when we were still using Python 2, but it's not useful anymore.

Comment: It looks like TF expects `FLAGS.output_path` to be a UTF-8-encoded file and it isn't.